# script for restore of postgres database localy from dump given on stdin - ambiguous redirect

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.3, psql, pg-dump

Runing this command:

`sshpass  -p "pass" ssh  x@1.2.3.4 "pg_dump -U foo some_db"`

runs perfectly fine. It returns on stdandard output the dump of db.

Then I would like to restore `new_db` based on dump redirected to stdin

```
 psql -U foo -d new_db < `sshpass  -p "pass" ssh  x@1.2.3.4 "pg_dump -U foo some_db"`
```

I got error: `ambiguous redirect`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest this :

```
sshpass  -p "pass" ssh  x@1.2.3.4 "pg_dump -U foo some_db" | psql -U foo -d new_db
```

This will pipe ssh standard output into psql standard input.